# How do I Remove Resource from Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I created a resource earlier

```
rails g active_admin:resource Question
```

How do I remove it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the rails destroy command:

```
rails destroy active_admin:resource <Resource Name>
```

Example:

```
rails generate active_admin:resource Question
    create  app/admin/questions.rb

rails destroy active_admin:resource Question
    remove  app/admin/questions.rb
```